# How to change the position of text in Input

Tags: react-native

[image: faulty text position]

How can I correct the textposition so it is not on the line but a bit above?

The current component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput, View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Input = ({ label, value, onChangeText, placeholder, secureTextEntry, multiline }) => {
  const { inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
  return (
    <View style={containerStyle}>
      <Text style={labelStyle}>{label}</Text>
      <TextInput
      multiline={multiline}
      secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
      placeholder={placeholder}
      autoCorrect={false}
      value={value}
      onChangeText={onChangeText}
      underlineColorAndroid='#38c179'
      style={inputStyle}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = {
  inputStyle: {
    color: 'white',
    paddingRight: 5,
    paddingLeft: 5,
    fontSize: 18,
    lineHeight: 23,
    flex: 2
  },
  labelStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginLeft: 15,
    flex: 1,
    color: 'white'
  },
  containerStyle: {
    height: 40,
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    marginBottom: 5
  }
};

export { Input };
```

Comment: if you add the whole component and create a [snack](https://snack.expo.io/)  reproducing the problem it'll be easier to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the container height, adding paddingBottom or set marginTop: -10 to the input. Also, alignItems center might cause the problem too, experiment with those.

Comment: It was alignItems center